# fix the orientation on page to landscape only in Jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, orientation, landscape

How can the orientation of a page be landscape only as i am using jquery mobile for my webapp?

The page contains some tabular data which can't be shown in the portrait mode in the mobile version...

Take a look of my layout.. http://jsfiddle.net/nY5ZF/1/

Can this be fixed???

Comment: Perhaps this can help you to lock landscape orientation? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009743/jquery-mobile-lock-orientation

Comment: srry but i tried this, its not working for me...

Comment: You either use @media or display data only when landscape view is active. Ask user to change orientation to see data.

Comment: But when?? if user rotates its smartphone or tablet at that point??

Comment: You can listen to [orientation change](http://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/). Hide data om portrait and show it on lanscape.

Comment: as if like this... http://jsfiddle.net/nY5ZF/6/

Comment: Yes exactly, hide data on portrait, show it on landscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now have responsive tables in jquerymobile 1.3.1, you could use that...

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/tables/

As its not possible to lock the orientation in webapps unlike hybrid apps (phonegap). Some browsers just do not help us in that.

Next you could display this data in list format OR just check the mode, if portrait then give a simple message "To view table please use landscape".

Comment: yes i think this is the perfect soln. for it, i have answered this ques. before jQm launches this feature... thanks for that...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [`orientation`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/) property of jQuery Mobile and set it to false.

`jQuery.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled = false;`

This should necessarily make a fall back on the resize window event. The resize can be handeled by `min-width` CSS3

http://jsfiddle.net/nY5ZF/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can't lock the rotation of the browser, but what you can do is use a diferent stylesheet for one orientation and another stylesheet that will hide everything in portrait mode.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_l.css" media="screen and (orientation: landscape)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_p.css" media="screen and (orientation: portrait)">
```

Comment: your idea is right but some what the tabular design dnt fit in mobile devices... That's why trying to find the solution for it...