# Jquery Mobile - Prevent Portrait Orientation...or Orientation at all?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, orientation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Mobile lock orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009743/jquery-mobile-lock-orientation)

Is there any way to prevent orientation to change?

I tried: `$.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled = false;`
but no success...

Any ideas???

Comment: you should take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009743/jquery-mobile-lock-orientation

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent  orientation to change, it's a behavior of safari.

You can show to the user a messagge to explain that your site is optimized for portrait or landscape view.