# Cordova ignores screen orientation lock

Tags: android, cordova, screen-orientation

I'm using Cordova 3.3.0 with my Galaxy S3 (running latest Cyanogenmod) to test an app I'm working on; I need the app screen to remain in "portrait" mode and be locked even if the user rotates the device.  No matter what I tried or tutorials I followed, the app is ignoring the preferences to lock the screen.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.numediaweb.test" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>
        Test.</description>
    <author href="http://test.com" email="abdel@test.com">
        me
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just found an interesting [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884724/portrait-orientation/20888376#20888376) after I posted the question (in the related widget right); It's a [bug in Cordova](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5634) and to fix it, you either edit the AndroidManifest.xml to something like;

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges=...
```

Or use a [plugin](https://github.com/cogitor/PhoneGap-OrientationLock).

FI prefer to edit the manifest as it is easy.

Comment: The drawback is when you delete/rebuild your Android platform; you have to add the changes again :( Another thing with the plugin is that if you want to start your Cordova application pre-locked you have to edit the onCreate() activity..

Comment: Provided plugin is deprecated, use this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32405384/1848600

Answer (score 14):

Fixed in Cordova **3.4.1**.
Now preference orientation works!

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Comment: I'm on 3.5.0 I do not think it is fixed. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6182

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to edit the android manifest like this:

```
    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name=".AppName"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
```

with unspecified android select the proper orientation for device. 
es. smartphone is portrait only, but tablet is portrait and landscape