# Meteor Cordova Orientation

Tags: meteor, meteor-cordova

I am attempting to lock the orientation of the meteor cordova build to portrait mode.

I have set up a top-level file called mobile-config.js

In that file I included:

```
App.setPreference('Orientation', 'portrait');
```

This seems to have no effect, it still switches to landscape mode. 
Does anyone know how I could implement portrait lock? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an open bug, check [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212345/725911) and [the bug itself here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6182).

Apparently the simplest way is to edit the `Manifest.xml` file directly (what comes out of the `meteor build` command), but I'd use [a plugin](https://github.com/cogitor/PhoneGap-OrientationLock) to avoid having to edit files manually after each build.

Bottom line, to fix it, wait for an official bug fix or meanwhile use a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have fixed it yet. I had a similar issue and resolved it for android app. Please note this solution has been tested for Meteor running on android device using:`meteor run android-device`. Meteor version is 1.3, also works on 1.3.1. Just stop your meteor server, uninstall the app from android device. Then inside the meteor project directory, `meteor reset`. Then `meteor run android-device`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Oops, just noted it was **2015** April :)