# How to create a full page ios app?

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova, meteor

Having tried a bunch of different methods I cannot seem to create a nicely fit fullscreen ios app (web app made in cordova) as there would always be overflow.

I have tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Which didn't fix anything either. I have also tried:

```
    overflow-x: hidden;
```

And that also didn't work. My CSS is as below:

```
body,html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden }

textbox {
width: 100%;
height: 42px;
padding: 20px 0px 25px 25px;
border: 0px;
outline: none;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-appearance: none;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px; }
```

How to create a fullscreen ios app in CSS that doesn't scroll vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Do  you test your app with an emulator or really with a phone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574309/meteor-cordova-orientation

only css can;t control the Orientation, try read this

Comment: @Rotan075 I have tested it on the actual iphone

Comment: @MoonFlyer I'm not really after the orientation, i just don't want overflow. So no scrolling in the app

Comment: Can you look in the generated source code if you can find the meta tag is generated? Because it should work! @LisaS

Answer (score 0):

In **mobile-config.js** file , add this line

```
App.setPreference('DisallowOverScroll', true);
```