# Lock orientation for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, phaser-framework

How would I lock the orientation for a mobile device using js, phaser or jquery? Is there a generic way to do it so it locks orientation regardless of the platform or device used?

I basically want to lock landscape mode for my browser based game.

Comment: Try to search on google or SO before posting - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009743/jquery-mobile-lock-orientation

Comment: I did Check this page however the solution here doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages

Answer (score 2):

There is a `forceOrientation` and a `forcePortrait` method in the `ScaleManager` class. [See docs](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.ScaleManager.html#forceLandscape).

We also usually use an image to ask the users to flip their phones.
As well, you can listen to the `incorrectOrientation` signal so know when the game is in the undesired orientation.

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using Intel XDK

```
intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation("landscape");
intel.xdk.device.setAutoRotate(false);
```