# Is there any way to restrict device(Ipad, Mobile, tablet) orientation in web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, web-applications

I have one web application and I am using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, angular, bootstrap and java to design web application.

I want to lock portrait mode of the device(Ipad, Mobile, tablet) for a particular web page.

Means that page can only view in landscape mode, User is not able to go in portrait mode.

So how to lock portrait mode.  Also, How automatically change the mode of the device(Portrait to Landscape) when users open the page.

Please solve my problem using above mentioned technology.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7010010/3058905

Comment: check this https://github.com/cogitor/PhoneGap-OrientationLock

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738072/forcing-web-site-to-show-in-landscape-mode-only